# PostgreSql NPGSL Duplicate Primary Key

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

How can you return the error or raise an exception when executing ExecuteNonQuery in NPGSQL when deliberately inserting a duplicated primary key. Upon execution, it just freezes and nothing happens. Ive tried surrounding the code with Try Catch but it still freezes in ExecuteNonQuery .

PS. Cant use AutoIncrement column.

EDIT:

```
        try
        {
            command = new NpgsqlCommand(strQuery, conn);
            if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
```

where strQuery is the command text. E.G. My table already has primary key value 1. Then I will deliberately insert another 1 as the primary key. How do you raise en exception?

When the return value is false. I will throw en exception. But it freezes in ExecuteNonQuery.

Comment: @mjwills Pls see update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Npgsql properly throws a PostgresException with [PostgreSQL error 23505](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/errcodes-appendix.html) (duplicate key value violates unique constraint), here's some code that shows it:

```
using (var conn = OpenConnection())
{
    using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("CREATE TABLE foo (id INT PRIMARY KEY)", conn))
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("INSERT INTO foo (id) VALUES (1)", conn))
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("INSERT INTO foo (id) VALUES (1)", conn))
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The problem is likely in your code. If you still think there's an issue, submit a full example, including which version of Npgsql you're using and a complete, runnable console program showing the issue (like I did in the fragment above).

Comment: Solved it. Apparently, the version used in the project was 2.x.x. Thanks. If you did not mention which version of the Npgsql is used, I wouldn't have bothered checking it.